# Run with multiple threads in many times

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario that includes 10 requests for users each 2 seconds apart,
runh with 100 user

but I don't know how to write the script properly.

Answer (score 1):

1. `runh with 100 user` - use the following [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) settings:

   [image]

   it means that each of 100 users will run 10 requests so you will have 1000 requests in total. If you need more - increase the "Loop Count" number
2. `10 requests` - put the relevant [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) children of the Thread Group

   [image]
3. `each 2 seconds apart` - if you want to have delay of 2 seconds between the requests add a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) at the [same level as the requests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) and set the desired delay there

   [image]